# Why something like optional chaining is not applied to all expressions and function calls in swift?

Tags: swift

If there is an ability of optional chaining in swift like `a?.b`, which returns optional of type of b, why there is no ability to unwrap optionals like this:

```
let x: Int? = 5, y: Int? = 6
let z: Int?
z = x? + y?
```

I mean: apply `+` (or any other function) if all the arguments have values, or return 'nil' otherwise. It looks very useful for me, so I am not sure, if I am not missing something understanding this.

Answer (score 1):

The `why` is not really answerable, it would be rather opinion based - although there's a good rationale from the Swift team for not implementing implicit stuff in the Swift realm.

But you can easily define a new `+` operator for your optional Ints:

```
func +(lhs: Int?, rhs: Int?) -> Int? {
    if let l = lhs, r = rhs {
        return l + r
    }
    return nil
}

let x: Int? = 5, y: Int? = 6
let z = x + y
```

Comment: Yes, I can. But I am still wondering, why there is no such behaviour out of the box, like with optional chaining. UPD: Okay, I see the edit

Comment: @AndriyKashchynets In addition to this answer, I thing it' worth mentioning that optional _chaining_ is used to access methods or properties of optional objects, and not really applicable in your example above. Optional chaining can be seen as an abortable single-directional flow, whereas your example above is if "forked" with regard to the possible optionality of x, y or x and y.

Comment: @dfri Yes, but almost always one is interested in the only case 'any of the arguments is nil' UPD: So, such default behaviour would not look unexpected

Answer (score 0):

You can also use flatmap to remove optionality and reduce to sum like this,

```
let z = [x, y].flatMap { $0 }.reduce(0, combine: +)
```